# If a real analytic function is zero at a point in a topological space, how does one prove that it is zero everywhere in that space?

Tags: general-topology, analytic-functions

I understand that an iterative argument can be used here, where one considers the points in a neighbourhood of the point at which the function is zero. However, I do not know how to go about proving this exactly.

In summary, I am trying to prove the strong unique continuation property of real analytic functions (in a topological space).

Comment: What is an analytic function in a topological space?

Comment: If you only assume the function is zero at a point, then the statement is false even in the case when it makes sense - $f(x)=x$ is analytic in $\mathbb R$ and zero at $0$, yet not zero everywhere.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Could you help me? I'm trying to prove the unique continuation property of real analytic functions and I am really struggling

Comment: @JS26 How can I help you if you don't tell me what is an analytic function in a topological space?

Comment: @Wojowu I feel kind of stupid now, basically my project is on the unique continuation of harmonic functions. I proved that harmonic functions are real analytic, and now if I show that real analytic functions have the unique continuation property then I will be done. I'm very confused as to how to show this.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Okay I'm clearly very wrong in saying that. I just want to know how to show that real analytic functions have the unique continuation property.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos :):):):):):):):):)

Comment: If $f$ is real analytic on some connected open $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and it vanishes on some open $V \subset U$ then $f = 0$ on $U$. Proof : around each $x \in U$ there is an open ball $W_x \ni x$ where $f$ is represented by a power series.

Assume $f(b) \ne 0$ for some $b \in U$, pick a finite length curve from $a \in V$ to $b$, the curve is compact so it is covered by finitely many $W_{x_i}$, you can add more points so that $x_{i+1} \in W_{x_i}$, and the identically zero propagates naturally from $W_{x_i}$ to $W_{x_{i+1}}$ thus to $b$.

Comment: ie. https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b8/Analytic_continuation_along_a_curve.png/220px-Analytic_continuation_along_a_curve.png

Comment: @reuns Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $I$ be an open interval in $\mathbb R$, let $J$ be another open interval, such that $J\supset I$, and let $f,g\colon J\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ be two analytic functions such that $f|_I=g|_I$. You want a proof of the fact that $f=g$, I suppose.

If $I=(a,b)$ and $b\in J$, then consider the power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-b)^n$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n(x-b)^n$ that represent $f$ and $g$ respectively near $b$. Then from the fact that $f=g$ to the left of $b$, you can deduce that $(\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}^+):a_n=b_n$ (since $a_n=\frac{f^{(n)}(b)}{n!}=\frac{g^{(n)}(b)}{n!}=b_n$). But then the equality $f(x)=g(x)$ is true in some interval $(a,b+\varepsilon)$. By the same argument, if $a\in J$, then the equality $f(x)=g(x)$ is true in some interval $(a-\varepsilon,b)$. So, you can always enlarge the interval $I$ and therefore $I=J$.